# Outlook 2007/2010 breaking horizontal columns with tables

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I've built an email which features images surrounded by a "polaroid" style border and caption.  To do that I built a table around the image with white backgrounds and all works fine except on Outlook 2007 and 2010. Here's how it should look (Outlook 2011 version):

[image]

And here's how it displays in 07/10, pushing the tables out of the width of the page and increasing the width of the tables hugely:

[image]

Here's the code I've used - the tables are the only elements that cause problems:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnImageBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
    <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="padding: 9px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" class="mcnImageBlockInner">
                <table align="left" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="width:164px;background-color:white;padding-right: 9px;padding-left: 9px;padding-top: 9px;padding-bottom:9px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="max-width:160px;border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;">
                                            <img mc:edit="product 1" class="mcnImage" width="100%" style="max-width:160px;">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" mc:edit="Caption 1" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-right: 18px;padding-bottom: 9px;padding-left: 18px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;background-color:white;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 11px;line-height: 150%;text-align: left;">
                                <center>&nbsp;</center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 0;padding-right: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;background-color:white;text-align: left;">
                                <img align="center" height="18" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/004beaebbdbc9392458d4bde2/images/shadow.1.gif" style="height: 18px;width:100%;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table's width is being set to 100% [of its parent container].

```
<table ... width="100%" ...></table>
```

The full code hasn't been given, but I can only assume its parent has a width greater than that of the content above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably uses css classes or IDs within an HTML email.

You should only use inline css styles and even them keep them to a bare minimum to ensure maximum email client compatibility.

I don't think using the max-width property will be doing you any favours either. I'd recommend simply setting the actual width on height on the images using the regular width and heights html tags.

Here's a good reference for html emails:

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails

Comment: Thanks. The table works fine with the classes stripped out - the max-width is unfortunately needed as it sets the size of the images users upload in Mailchimp, so there's no way of getting around using that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code (I suggest using this as an embedded style), this always fixes a lot of my Outlook 2007/2010/2013 spacing issues:

table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }